# Move Cursor One Word at a Time in UTextView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextview, text-cursor

I would like to create a button that moves the cursor position in a UITextView one word at a time. From a user perspective, this would be the same as Option-Right Arrow in Mac OS X, which is defined as "go to the word to the right of the insertion point."

I have found a couple ways to move on character at a time. How would you modify this to move one word at a time?

```
- (IBAction)rightArrowButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
     myTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(myTextView.selectedRange.location + 1, 0); 
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Was able to implement it like this,

```
- (IBAction)nextWord {
    NSRange selectedRange = self.textView.selectedRange;
    NSInteger currentLocation = selectedRange.location + selectedRange.length;
    NSInteger textLength = [self.textView.text length];

    if ( currentLocation == textLength ) {
        return;
    }

    NSRange newRange = [self.textView.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]
                                                           options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                                             range:NSMakeRange((currentLocation + 1), (textLength - 1 - currentLocation))];
    if ( newRange.location != NSNotFound ) {
        self.textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(newRange.location, 0);
    } else {
        self.textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(textLength, 0);
    }
}

- (IBAction)previousWord {
    NSRange selectedRange = self.textView.selectedRange;
    NSInteger currentLocation = selectedRange.location;

    if ( currentLocation == 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    NSRange newRange = [self.textView.text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]
                                                           options:NSBackwardsSearch
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, (currentLocation - 1))];
    if ( newRange.location != NSNotFound ) {
        self.textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange((newRange.location + 1), 0);
    } else {
        self.textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It is very close to what I was looking for and puts me on the right path. Much appreciated.

Comment: nextWord puts the cursor in front of the next word (as the name implies). I am trying to move the cursor after the current word (like OS X Option-Right Arrow). Fiddled with search type and range options but am not having success.  previousWord is working as expected.

Comment: To clarify further, if Mac OS X finds you're already at the end of a word it will jump to the end of the next word.

Comment: Doh! I tried + 1 to the currentLocation, but did not subtract it from the textLength. Thank you very much for your assistance.