# Move Cursor One Word(including language like Chinese) at a Time in UTextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cursor, uitextview

[I have read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273323/move-cursor-one-word-at-a-time-in-utextview),but it can only work well in English for it just use white-space and something like NewlineCharacterSet as separator.
I want to add a left arrow and a right arrow in the accessory input view to move the cursor in `UITextView` by words.
And I am wondering how to support that feature for some Asian languages like Chinese

PS:I will added an example that CFStringTokenizer failed to work with when there are both English Characters and Chinese characters

```
test string: 
Happy Christmas! Text view test 云存储容器测试开心 yeap
the expected boundaries: 
Happy/ Christmas!/ Text/ view/ test/ 云/存储/容器/测试/开心/ yeap/
the boundaries show in reality: 
Happy/ Christmas!/ Text/ view/ test/ 云存储容器测试开心/ yeap/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally I use `UITextInputTokenizer` to realized the function

Comment: Sry for later reply. Read the `UITextInputTokenizer` documentary. It can solve the problem to some extent

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak Chinese, but according to the documentation,
`CFStringTokenizer` is able to find word boundaries in many languages,
including Asian languages.

The following code shows how to advance from one word ("world" at position 6)
to the next word ("This" at position 13):

```
// Test string.
NSString *string = @"Hello world. This is great.";

// Create tokenizer
CFStringTokenizerRef tokenizer = CFStringTokenizerCreate(NULL,
                             (__bridge CFStringRef)(string),
                             CFRangeMake(0, [string length]),
                             kCFStringTokenizerUnitWordBoundary,
                             CFLocaleCopyCurrent());

// Start with a position that is inside the word "world".
CFIndex position = 6;

// Goto current token ("world")
CFStringTokenizerTokenType tokenType;
tokenType = CFStringTokenizerGoToTokenAtIndex(tokenizer, position);
if (tokenType != kCFStringTokenizerTokenNone) {
    // Advance to next "normal" token:
    tokenType = CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken(tokenizer);
    while (tokenType != kCFStringTokenizerTokenNone && tokenType != kCFStringTokenizerTokenNormal) {
        tokenType = CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken(tokenizer);
    }

    if (tokenType != kCFStringTokenizerTokenNone) {
        // Get the location of next token in the string:
        CFRange range = CFStringTokenizerGetCurrentTokenRange(tokenizer);
        position = range.location;
        NSLog(@"%ld", position);
        // Output: 13 = position of the word "This"
    }
}
```

There is no `CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToPreviousToken()` function, so to move to
the previous word you have to start at the beginning of the string and advance forward.

Comment: thanks for reply, and I find it doesn't work well when there are both Chinese characters and English characters in the textview.

Comment: @Roger: OK. - Perhaps you could add a small example text to your question that demonstrates the problem, together with the expected word boundaries.

Comment: And you can move the position backward and use the CFStringTokenizerGoToTokenAtIndex() function to find the position of word backward

Comment: @Roger: The argument to CFStringTokenizerGoToTokenAtIndex is a position in the original string, not the index of the token.

Comment: My meaning is that we can get the location(position in the string) of the current tokenizer from its range ,then we can find the tokenizer at (range.location - 1) to get the backward word.

Comment: @Roger: Oh yes, you are right! - I made some tests with your text (unfortunately my knowledge of Chinese is zero). - But it seems that if you don't restrict the result to kCFStringTokenizerTokenNormal, but allow all tokens that are != kCFStringTokenizerTokenNone, then you get better results. (You will also get tokens for the spaces between the words, but it should be possible to skip those.)

Comment: I finally used `UITextInputTokenizer` to realize it.